# JSP, Getting values from Text box into another JSP page

Tags: jsp, textbox

I am having a jsp page i.e. source page, where I get values entered by the user into a **Text Box** and When the **Next** button is clicked I need to get the values entered by the user in the previous page displayed in the **target page or the Next page**. I tried all the codes that have been given as examples but unable to succeed. Kindly help me out a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the textbox in a form tag where the action will equal your servlet name.  Then when the user hits submit or next you can get the value in your servlet using the request.getParmeter() if you want to process it.  Then you can set that value in a response object that you forward to the next page.  Or you can put it in the session object if you have to use it more than once throughout your application.   Sorry I don't have the time to test the code below, but that is the general idea.

On your jsp

```
<form action="servletName" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
-------
<input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

On your servlet

```
 @Override public final void doPost(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
   ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
  ) throws ServletException, IOException {

String email=request.getParameter("email");

-------
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);

}
```

Next jsp

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.print(request.getAttribute("email").toString())
```